# getting images to show side by side in matlab

Tags: matlab

Am trying to get 3 images to be show side by side in matlab. But when I use subplot they are being spaced out unevenly. The first and second is a 25-by-25 pxl image and the third is a 25-by-75 image.

How can i get it to be show like

```
+-----++-----++---------------+
| img || img ||     img       |
|  1  ||  2  ||      3        |
+-----++-----++---------------+
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `subplot` to span multiple grid squares.  For your example try

```
subplot(1,4,1)
subplot(1,4,2)
subplot(1,4,3:4) % this will expand the third axes over the last two grid squares
```

Note:

The position of the axes can be `h=subplot(...)` returns the handle to the newly created axes.  You can then use `set` to adjust the axes or you can use

```
h=subplot('position', [left bottom width height])
```

manually place the axes in the figure. Also, note the functions `get(h,'prop')` and `set(h,'prop',value)` are also available to adjust other axes properties. See the MATHWORK's [handle graphics browser](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/infotool/hgprop/axes_frame.html) section on axes for documentation on all the available properties.

Comment: It worked like a charm, but I have two questions, the images are coming out discolored, and is there a way I can get them to almost touch?

Comment: @cubearth See updates to my answer for adjusting the subplot positions.  Not sure what's happening with the image colors. Need more information to help you there.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative is to create a new image:

```
abuttedImage = [im1 im2 im3];
```

This will work as long as the number of rows in each image are the same.